# Adding column to pandas data frame that provides labels based on condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a data frame filled with time series temperature data and need to label the equipment status as 'good' or 'bad' based on the temperature. It is 'good' if it is between 35 and 45 and 'bad' otherwise. However, I want to add a condition that if it returns to the appropriate temperature range after being listed as 'bad' it must be 'good' for a least 2 days before it is labeled as 'good' again. So far, I can label on a more basic level, but struggling with implementing the more complicated label switch.

```
df['status'] = ['bad' if x <35 or x >45 else 'good' for x in df['temp']]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about an approach like this?

You can make a group_check function for each row, and check if that row has any neighboring offending temperature within the group from the broader df.

This will only check the previous measurements. You would need to do a quick boolean check against the current measurement to confirm the prior measurements are OK AND the current measurement is OK.

```
def group_check_maker(index, row):
    def group_check(group):
        if len(group) > 1:
          if index in group.index:
            failed_status = False
            for index2, row2 in group.drop(index).iterrows():
              if (row['Date'] > row2['Date']) and (row['Date'] - row2['Date'] < pd.Timedelta(days = 2)) and (row2['Temperature'] < 35 or row2['Temperature'] >45):
                  failed_status = True
            if failed_status:
                return 'Bad'
            else:
                return 'Good'

    return group_check

def row_checker_maker(df):
    def row_checker(row):
        group_check = group_check_maker(row.name, row)
        return df[df['Equipment ID'] == row['Equipment ID']].groupby('Equipment ID').apply(group_check).iloc[0]
    return row_checker

row_checker = row_checker_maker(df)

df['Neighboring Day Status'] = df.apply(row_checker, axis = 1)
```

Comment: Amazingly helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np    
df['status'] = np.where((df['temp']>35) | (df['temp']>45) , 'bad', 'good')
```

This should solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you, but I am trying to implement a more complicated condition. I want to make it so that if that label is 'bad' then goes back to the appropriate temperature range, it can't be listed as 'good' again until it is between 35 and 45 for at least 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a `pd.Series` with the value 'bad' that you replace values [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)  its is betweem 35 and 45, then propagate the value 'bad' to the next two empty rows with `ffill` and a limit of 2 and finally [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) the rest with good such as:

```
#dummy df
df = pd.DataFrame({'temp': [36, 39, 24, 34 ,56, 42, 40, 38, 36, 37, 32, 36, 23]})

df['status'] = pd.Series('bad', index=df.index).where(df.temp.lt(35)|df.temp.gt(45))\
                                               .ffill(limit=2).fillna('good')
print (df)
    temp status
0     36   good
1     39   good
2     24    bad
3     34    bad
4     56    bad
5     42    bad #here it is 42 but the previous row is bad so still bad
6     40    bad #here it is 40 but the second previous row is bad so still bad
7     38   good #here it is good then
8     36   good
9     37   good
10    32    bad
11    36    bad
12    23    bad
```

Comment: The only problem with this approach is if there is a day that is missing data or if there is a day that has two readings.

Comment: @AdamZeldin indeed but the OP did not give any input data nor specify missing values or two same dates. Also, while your method fits OP's requirements, I hope the data is not to huge otherwise using two `apply` plus `iterrows` within one of the function, with `groubpy` on a dataframe that is already containing one group (btw how do you know there is a column `Equipment ID`??) will be really long!

Comment: It was my implicit assumption that the equipment status could be measured more frequently than daily and for different pieces of equipment. “Equipment ID” was arbitrary. Good point about the performance. If the dataset is huge, perhaps a running average temperature could be taken as a prep step.

Comment: @AdamZeldin so implicit assumption are different for everybody then ;) you are right about a running average or maybe a resample daily as a prep step could do the job!